# redirect inside a redux action with react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I am new to react. I have a component called `Register.js` there I call a redux action's method `register`. So inside that I want to redirect user to path `/dashboard` after the dispatch.
This is my action inside redux

```
const { REGISTER_USER } = require('./types')
export const register = (values) => async dispatch => {

    try {
        // register part goes here ...

        dispatch({
            type: REGISTER_USER,
            payload: values
        })

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

How do I achive this in react?

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use react router and the history functionality to push to a new page after the action has dispatched and resolved (e.g. the user has registered)

[React router redirect after action redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35706835/react-router-redirect-after-action-redux)

Be aware newer versions of react router behave differently

[How to push to History in React Router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4)

Another option would be having "register" as a modal, and once submitted you just hide the modal from view and refresh the dashboard component with the new props (so it'd go and fetch data for the newly authenticated user)

You wouldn't want to redirect in the action or redux reducer/state files, it'd be in your react component logic.